# Is it possible to trigger dependent job in Jenkins BEFORE main job starts?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, build-tools

There are few jobs: **A**, **B** and Others.
**A** depends from **B**, i.e **A** job triggers **B** one, but no vice versa.
**A** and **B** cannot be run simultaneously.

So, the problem is that the jobs lock each other: **A** waits while **B** will be finished, when **B** can't start, because **A** is started (is waiting for completion of **B**).

Is it possible to trigger **B** job BEFORE **A** job starts?

Up- and downstream features and found plugins can't solve the issue. Some other jobs can start **B** job too. Any of the jobs have not any artifact dependencies.

Any ideas?

Comment: I can't figure out what your problem is. You can click "Build Now" (or the API, or the CLI etc.) to build job B.

Comment: It should be triggered automatically by commits: found new commit -> A triggers B job as commit is found -> B job finishes and A job starts.

Right now: A job STARTS (after commit)  and trigger B job, but they can't be run simultaneously and jobs are waiting each other completion...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said @Mahi, [Build+Flow+Plugin](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin) can solve the issue. 
Besides I'm confused why so many simple features are missing in Jenkins. Plugins solves some of them somehow, but anyway it's terrible for the Jenkins project itself.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this
[Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin)

Post build action -> Trigger parametrized build on other project

Comment: Yeah, I have the plugin, but I do not need that trigger (**B** triggers **A**). I need to start and complete **B** job before starting of job **A** like in Teamcity, where the build **A** is only queued and waits for finishing of **B**

Comment: this plugin will help you

Comment: Thanks @Mahi. [Build Flow Plugin] (wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin) can really solve the issue.